# Minimal polynomial of $f(A) = A^t$

Tags: linear-algebra, minimal-polynomials

Let $f:\mathbb{R^{n\times n}\to \mathbb{R^{n\times n}}}$ with $f(A)=A^t,n\ge1$. Find the minimal polynomial of $f$.

My try:

The standard basis for the matrices in $\mathbb{R^{n\times n}}$ is the collection of matrices with $1$ in a position and $0s$ in all other positions: $A_{11}=\begin{bmatrix} 1&0&\dots&0\\0\\.\\.\\.\\0&0&\dots&0\end{bmatrix},A_{12}=\begin{bmatrix} 0&1&\dots&0\\0\\.\\.\\.\\0&0&\dots&0\end{bmatrix},$etc.

Now, for all $A_{ii}$ matrices: $f(A_{ii})=A_{ii}$ and for all $A_{ij}:f(A_{ij})=0,i\ne j$. Thus, the matrix representation of $f$ is: $A_f=\begin{bmatrix}A_{11}& \dots &0\\0&A_{22} \cdots&0 \\.\\.\\.\\0& \cdots&A_{nn}\end{bmatrix}$ and its minimal polynomial is the GCD of all $m_{A_{ii}}(x)$ minimal polynomials which are all equal to $(-x)^n(1-x)$ so, $m_{A_f}(x)=(-x)^n(1-x)$.

According to the textbook's answer, I'm terribly wrong. Any help?

Comment: $f(A_{ij})=A_{ji},i\ne j$

Answer (score 5):

**Hint:** $f^2(A) = A$.  So, the minimal polynomial divides $x^2 - 1$.

Comment: Why is $f^2(A) =A$

Comment: @AlexMatt What happens if you transpose a matrix twice?

Comment: So, for every matrix $A$, $f^2(A)=1 \cdot A$ , so $1$ is an eigenvalue of $f$? what about $-1$?

Comment: @AlexMatt both $1$ and $-1$ **might** be eigenvalues of $f$ (in fact, both of them are).  The key point is that there can be no other eigenvalues, since every eigenvalue must be a zero of the minimal polynomial.

Comment: @AlexMatt For what it's worth: note that the matrices
$$
\pmatrix{0&1\\1&0}, \quad \pmatrix{0&1\\-1&0}
$$
are eigenvectors associated with $1$ and $-1$, respectively.

Comment: I don't quite understand why $f^2(A) =A$ tells me that its minimal polynomial divides $x^2-1$

Comment: $p(x) = x^2 - 1$ is a polynomial satisfying $p(A) = 0$.  Therefore, the minimal polynomial of $A$ must divide $p$. This is a fundamental result regarding minimal polynomials.

Answer (score 0):

For all $A \in \mathbb{R^{n\times n}}$:
$$ A = \frac{A + A^t}{2} + \frac{A - A^t}{2}$$ where $\frac{A + A^t}{2}$ is symmetric and $\frac{A - A^t}{2}$ antisymmetric.

Moreover the only symmetric ($f(A) = A$) and antisymmetric ($f(A) = - A$) matrix is the zero matrix.

**This proves that $f$ is diagonalizable** with eigenvalues $1,-1$. Therefore the minimal polynomial of $f$ is $x^2-1$.